# Phonegap: How can I prevent the 'Beep'/'Vibration' when a hold touch events occurs?

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins

The application loses most of it's functionality because it has this default feature when a touch event is hold. Is there a way to prevent this behaviour using an existing plugin?

Comment: I've never seen the behaviour you describe. Maybe should you provide more details about the platform you use, how you create your app...

Comment: I think the feature is only in Android, it's called Haptic Feedback. I have a 'touchstart' and 'touchend' event on an `<div>` and when I hold the 'touchstart' after 1 second it makes some vibration and when I release it there is also the 'beep'. So I tried to do a plugin to prevent this behaviour but that's another problem I got later on: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23246435/phonegap-plugin-is-not-working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have just put my plugin, that do what you want, into GitHub repository. (I had similar problem.) Plugin disables sounds on touch (and also click) events. Don't affect other activities or dialogs.

https://github.com/VVelda/device-feedback

PS: What vibration do you mean? **Long press**? That can be disabled by disabling this type of event in CSS. Use this code:

```
* {
    -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0,0,0,0)
} body {
    -webkit-touch-callout: none;
    -webkit-text-size-adjust: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none
}
```

I don't know if -webkit-tap-highlight-color and -webkit-text-size-adjust have influence to this, probably no. But you never know.